# GitHub build-push-action and gha cache, should I set the github.ref_name in the scope?

Tags: docker, github, continuous-integration, github-actions, buildx

This is my build-push-action using gha cache. I'm bulding multiple images, i.e. `foo/bar:latest`, `foo/bar:2.8` and `env.tag` variable in the workflow is the full image name with tag.

From the documentation:

> By default, cache is scoped per Git branch. This ensures a separate cache environment for the main branch and each feature branch. If you build multiple images on the same branch, each build will overwrite the cache of the previous, leaving only the final cache.

I just want to be sure of doing the cache the "right way", passing `env.tag` as `scope`? Does GitHub cache still use the branch as stated, or should I pass `${{ github.ref_name }}-${{ env.tag }}` as `scope`?

```
    - name: Build and push
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
      env:
        tag: "${{ env.image }}:${{ matrix.version }}"
      with:
        context: "{{defaultContext}}:docker/caddy"
        target: ${{ matrix.target }}
        push: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
        tags: ${{env.tag }}
        build-args: |
          BASE_IMAGE=${{ matrix.version }}
        cache-from: type=gha,scope=${{ env.tag }}
        cache-to: type=gha,mode=max,scope=${{ env.tag }}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Scope](https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/backends/gha/#scope):

> To preserve the cache for multiple builds on the same branch, you can manually specify a cache scope name using the `scope` parameter.
> In the following example, the cache is set to a **combination of the branch name and the image name**, to ensure each image gets its own cache):

And, the next example shows sample configuration of `scope` for `image` and `image2` in conjunction with the branch name:

```bash
$ docker buildx build --push -t <registry>/<image> \
  --cache-to type=gha,url=...,token=...,scope=$GITHUB_REF_NAME-image \
  --cache-from type=gha,url=...,token=...,scope=$GITHUB_REF_NAME-image .

$ docker buildx build --push -t <registry>/<image2> \
  --cache-to type=gha,url=...,token=...,scope=$GITHUB_REF_NAME-image2 \
  --cache-from type=gha,url=...,token=...,scope=$GITHUB_REF_NAME-image2 .
```

Given this, your configured name for `scope` should be used `scope=<branch>-<image>` e.g.:

```
scope=${{ github.ref_name }}-image
```

Comment: So you would use `<branch-><image>` (i.e. `master-foo/bar`) OR - as the question asks - `master-foo/bar:2.8`, `master-foo/bar:latest ` and so on? In other words, should I put also the version in the scope?

Comment: @gremo: Yes, that what I understood from your question and the docs. I believe that your `env.tag` represents the image tag so your `scope` will be `scope=master-foo/bar:${{env.tag}}`.

Comment: So in the end, scope should involve <branch>-<image-><tag> right?

Comment: @gremo: I just looked at [GitHub Actions cache (experimental)](https://github.com/moby/buildkit#github-actions-cache-experimental). Looks like it could be any unique string that may be used as the `scope` name. The idea seems to be to have a unique cache per object that is to be cached.

Comment: forgive me, but If the scope is really "unique" (something that change at every push, for example)... what's the point of having a cache? On subsequent pushes, the old cache item isn't retrieved (cache miss), so cache would be useless :/

Comment: @gremo: Unique per branch and per image. Not to be overwritten by the subsequent caches on the same branch as in the case of one single name for all the images. That's not unique on consecutive pushes. For pushes on the same branch, it should work as a common cache. BTW, have you tested it on your side?